# Visual Studio stuck at “Resuming Suspended work”

Tags: visual-studio, resume, suspend

I am using Visual studio 2017. 
I suspended my work from the 'My Work' page. When trying to resume it,the visual studio got stuck on the process, showing this window:
[Resuming Suspended work window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsmTv.png)

This Task is completely stuck. I can't cancel the request, nor doing anything else with it and I'm afraid to shut it down from Task Manager and risk losing my work.

Do you have any ideas what can I do to solve this problem or at least protect my work?

Comment: Do check if there isn't an open Dialog hiding behind VS. That still happens.  Use Alt Tab , Windows-M, try to drag that window. But if that isn't it,  after 10 minutes or so of waiting you have little choice left but use TaskMan. On the plus side, VS won't lose work so easily.

Comment: By the end It was closed by itself.
After opening a new Visual studio task, The resumed work was already open under 'My Work' window, and also there was a suspended copy of it under the "Suspended work" menu.
Hoping to avoid conflicts,I Pressed the right button on the suspended copy and chose "Merge in the process". 
I'm glad to report there were no conflicts involved and that the work is now opened with all of my files.